# Проблема с редактированием файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Суть такова:

Имеется парсер

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
import os

def shimparser_local():
        with open('log.txt') as input_file, open('shims.c', 'a') as output_file:
            text = input_file.read()
            pat = r"""cannot\s*locate\s*symbol\s*"(.+?)"\s*referenced\s*"""
            for symbol in re.findall(pat, text):
                part_one = "#include <stdint.h>\nvoid "
                part_two = "{}".format(symbol)
                part_three = "(){}\n"
                part_four = "}\n"
                shim = (part_one + part_two + part_three + part_four)
                output_file.write(shim)

        File = open('shims.c', 'r')
        str_list = set()
        for i in File.readlines():
            if i not in str_list:
                str_list.add(i)
        File.close()
        File = open('shims.c', 'w')
        for j in str_list:
            File.write(j)
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
shimparser_local()
```

Данным парсером парсится файл с таким содержимым:

```
F/libc    ( 3391): CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/vendor/bin/mnld": cannot locate symbol "mtk_gps_get_mnl_info" referenced by "/system/vendor/bin/mnld"...
F/libc    ( 3390): CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/vendor/bin/mtk_agpsd": cannot locate symbol "SSL_get_client_random" referenced by "/system/vendor/bin/mtk_agpsd"...
F/libc    ( 3391): CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/vendor/bin/mnld": cannot locate symbol "mtk_gps_get_mnl_info" referenced by "/system/vendor/bin/mnld"...
F/libc    ( 3390): CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/vendor/bin/mtk_agpsd": cannot locate symbol "SSL_get_client_random" referenced by "/system/vendor/bin/mtk_agpsd"...
F/libc    ( 3391): CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/vendor/bin/mnld": cannot locate symbol "mtk_gps_get_mnl_info" referenced by "/system/vendor/bin/mnld"...
F/libc    ( 3390): CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/vendor/bin/mtk_agpsd": cannot locate symbol "SSL_get_client_random" referenced by "/system/vendor/bin/mtk_agpsd"...
F/libc    ( 3391): CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/vendor/bin/mnld": cannot locate symbol "mtk_gps_get_mnl_info" referenced by "/system/vendor/bin/mnld"...
F/libc    ( 3390): CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/vendor/bin/mtk_agpsd": cannot locate symbol "SSL_get_client_random" referenced by "/system/vendor/bin/mtk_agpsd"...
F/libc    ( 3391): CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/vendor/bin/mnld": cannot locate symbol "mtk_gps_get_mnl_info" referenced by "/system/vendor/bin/mnld"...
F/libc    ( 3390): CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/vendor/bin/mtk_agpsd": cannot locate symbol "SSL_get_client_random" referenced by "/system/vendor/bin/mtk_agpsd"...
F/libc    ( 3391): CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/vendor/bin/mnld": cannot locate symbol "mtk_gps_get_mnl_info" referenced by "/system/vendor/bin/mnld"...
F/libc    ( 3390): CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/vendor/bin/mtk_agpsd": cannot locate symbol "SSL_get_client_random" referenced by "/system/vendor/bin/mtk_agpsd"...
```

И отсекаются дубликаты. 
Во время парсинга данные дозаписываются в файл shims.c с таким содержимым:

```
extern "C" {
```

И на выходе получается что-то вроде:

```
#include <stdint.h>
extern "C" {
void mtk_gps_get_mnl_info(){}
void SSL_get_client_random(){}
void mtk_gps_get_mnl_info(){}
void SSL_get_client_random(){}
void mtk_gps_get_mnl_info(){}
void SSL_get_client_random(){}
void mtk_gps_get_mnl_info(){}
void SSL_get_client_random(){}
}
```

Но проблема в том что при проверке на дубликаты на выходе получается что-то похожее на:

```
#include <stdint.h>
void SSL_get_client_random(){}
extern "C" {
void mtk_gps_get_mnl_info(){}
}
```

А должно:

```
#include <stdint.h>
extern "C" {
void mtk_gps_get_mnl_info(){}
void SSL_get_client_random(){}
}
```

Если же в проверке на дубликаты сменить режим записи `w` на режим дозаписи `a` то на выходе получится что-то вроде:

```
extern "C" {
#include <stdint.h>
void mtk_gps_get_mnl_info(){}
}
#include <stdint.h>
void SSL_get_client_random(){}
}
#include <stdint.h>
void mtk_gps_get_mnl_info(){}
}
#include <stdint.h>
void SSL_get_client_random(){}
}
#include <stdint.h>
void mtk_gps_get_mnl_info(){}
}
```

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Судя по коду, вы зачем-то трижды открываете один и тот же файл, делая манипуляции с его содержимым. То, что строки в файл пишутся не по порядку, может быть связано с буферизацией. На вашем месте я бы сначала считал исходный файл в переменную, закрыл бы его, обработал содержимое переменной так, как мне нужно и записал бы его в выходной файл. 1 раз.

Comment: Да у вас тут еще и множества (set), а они не хранят данные в том порядке, в котором вы их туда записали

Comment: @strawdog можно пример?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** - с сохранением порядка строк

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
import os

def shimparser_local():
        header="#include <stdint.h>\nextern \"C\" {"
        res=[]
        with open('libc.txt') as input_file:
            text = input_file.read()
            pat = r"""cannot\s*locate\s*symbol\s*"(.+?)"\s*referenced\s*"""
            for symbol in re.findall(pat, text):
                part_one = "void "
                part_two = "{}".format(symbol)
                part_three = "(){}\n"
                part_four = "}\n"
                shim = (part_one + part_two + part_three + part_four)
                res.append(shim)
        # вот здесь будет ваш код записи данных в файл                
        print(header)
        mydict ={x:y for y, x in {v:k for k,v in enumerate(res)}.items()}
        for i in sorted(mydict.keys()):
            print(mydict[i], end="")


shimparser_local()
```

Если на вход дать приведенный вами пример, то на выходе будет:

```
#include <stdint.h>
extern "C" {
void mtk_gps_get_mnl_info(){}
}
void SSL_get_client_random(){}
}
```

И старайтесь работать с файлами через контекстные менеджеры, раз уж вы забываете их закрывать методом `.close()`.

Comment: немного не такой выхлоп.. как сделать его таким как в вопросе без продублированных строк (если они будут)?

Comment: @AndrewGoldman, то есть, вас не устраивает порядок? это издержки функционала пайтоновских `set`.

Comment: просто дальше из этого файла будет компилироваться .so библиотека.. поэтому нужна такая структура как в вопросе

Comment: @AndrewGoldman обновил ответ